# What all changes need to do while deploying hyperledger fabric-composer business network on two different VMs?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm deploying hyperledger fabric-composer business network on 2 different VMs.
So what changes i need to do in docker-compose.yaml, connection.json and commands of composer card create?

Comment: does anyone deployed multi org in multiple server machines for hyperledger fabric-composer business network?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've configured your Hyperledger Fabric nodes for two independent Orgs on two separate VMs (eg. peers, CA servers, certs,  configured the channel the business network is being deployed to etc) you can configure the connection profile info, that needs to be created to go into the business network identity cards that the peer Admins will need (eg. for runtime install on respective peers or a separate profile and therefore BN card, for instantiating the business network once, across peers from both Orgs) and other identities (eg administrators, other identities). See this tutorial for an idea of what is involved https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html  (obviously this is all 'local' docker containers for nodes in respective Orgs but you get the picture) and it is using the sample Fabric BYFN network as referred to [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html) but you get